# How do you lower the memory when rendering an image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, image

I want to render this 3D tree branch model into a transparent 2D PNG image. This way I can reuse it on other projects like a tree I'm making but I don't want it taking too much memory on my blender files if I duplicate it. How do I decrease the image memory while keeping it high quality? Also, I'm doing this on the cycles engine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Avoid alpha transparency. Here's a really useful vid by Blender Guru hat explains why to avoid alpha transparency https://youtu.be/8gSyEpt4-60?si=Y5xEFb7llbkchnA7&t=1761

Comment: So, this'll lower the memory count? I don't want my computer lagging, crashing, or rendering a really long time because I'm afraid every time I take a photo and duplicate it's going to eat up my memory.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean?
If you meant low usage of RAM, i don't think you can do that.

If you meant storage tho, you can compress it with 7z:

First, download 7z: https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Second, set it up.

Third, right click on your file > 7-Zip > Archive...

Fourth:
[image]

And here you go:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: Sorry, doing it now.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I really don't want to bug you, but English is the mandatory language for the website. Please change your screenshot so that it can be understood by everyone.